# @RequestMapping("/") from Spring Boot Returns 404 pages only

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

In spring boot, there is no problem in any URL, such as localhost:8080/anything, but only in the default URL, such as localhost:8080/ or localhost:8080.

IDE is currently using Intellij.

This is not being done.
I tried to grab a breakpoint to try debugging, but I didn't run that method in the first place

During debugging, it was confirmed whether a bean was generated or not, but it was confirmed that a bean was generated without problem.

---

This is not being done.
I tried to grab a breakpoint to try debugging, but I didn't run that method in the first place

During debugging, it was confirmed whether a bean was generated or not, but it was confirmed that a bean was generated without problem.

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

---

It works normally.
Whatever URI is set, it works fine.

```
@Slf4j
    @Controller
    public class HomeController {
        @RequestMapping("/anyting")
        public String index(){
            return "index";
        }
    }
```

---

My sauce is as follows What should I check?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: If you are using @RequestMapping, you need to specify the method to use, such as GET, POST, PATCH etc, otherwise it will map any request.

Comment: `logging.level.web=debug`, please (hi & welcome!)

Comment: @MarcusCvjeticanin 
Of course, I tried that method, but it wasn't a solution to this problem, so I presented a concise code.

Comment: @xerx593 Thank you for welcoming me
[classpath [static/], classpath [public/], classpath [], classpath [resources/], classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [META-INF/resources/webjars/]]

Comment: As a result of checking, it seems that we are looking for resources in the following path However, in my case, the file is kept in /resource/template. How do I specify this?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving this it works:

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @GetMapping("")
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work


Answer (score 0):

**You can try with the below approaches:**

***1) Use @Controller along with @ResponseBody***

`@Controller` is used to mark classes as Spring MVC Controller.If you use only `@Controller` , you have to specify the `@ResponseBody` as well in each API methods.

```
@Controller
@Slf4j
public class HomeController {

  @RequestMapping("/")
  @ResponseBody
  public String index() {
    return "index";
  }

  @RequestMapping("/anything")
  @ResponseBody
  public String index2() {
    return "index";
  }

}
```

**Output:** The above code will return the "index" string as a response of this API.

If you want to show index.html page, then you have to modify your code as below and **please note your index.html should be placed in resources/static folder**.

```
@RequestMapping("/")
@ResponseBody
  public ModelAndView index() {
    return new ModelAndView("index.html");
  }
```

**Output:** This will redirect you to index.html page.

***2) Use @RestController***

`@RestController` annotation is a special controller used in RESTful Web services, and it's the combination of @Controller and @ResponseBody annotation. It is a specialised version of @Component annotation.

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class HomeController {

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String index() {
    return "index";
  }

  @RequestMapping("/anything")
  public String index2() {
    return "index";
  }
}
```

**Output:** The above code will return the "index" string as a response of this API.

If you want to show index.html page, then you have to modify your code as below and **please note your index.html should be placed in resources/static folder**.

```
@RequestMapping("/")
  public ModelAndView index() {
    return new ModelAndView("index.html");
  }
```

**Output:** This will redirect you to index.html page.

Comment: I tried that method, but it wasn't a solution to this problem, so I presented a concise code.

Comment: @terius : I have updated my solution with two approaches, you can try with any of them. For me, its working with both.

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem:

Not sure/cannot reporoduce!

To achieve: serving `templates/index.html` from a request to `<context_root>/` in a "default [spring-starter-web-thymeleaf](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.7.4&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=web,thymeleaf)"

#### Solution:

1. Delete this controller (if it doesn't anything than returning the view)
2. Place a (thymeleaf) view at `<project_root>/src/main/resources/templates/index.html` (e.g.:

   ```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head> 
        <title>Hello</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello, [[${param.name}?:'Dear']]!</p>
    </body>
    </html>
   ```
3. Issuing http://localhost:8080/ will give us:

   [image: success screenshot]

#### When Controller *does* some additional BL

I could work around like:

```java
@Controller ... class ... { // @RestController returns rather a "response body" than the "view name".
  @RequestMapping("/"/*, add more here!?*/) // !
  public String index(/*...*/){
    // do something useful..., then:
    return "index";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

everyone. Thank you for answering my question.

but it didn't have solve on me.

Instead, we will solve it in another way and share it with you.

The first word of @xerx593,
I got a hint from telling me to set the logging level to debug.

```js
2022-10-13 16:54:01.710 DEBUG 79836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/", parameters={}
2022-10-13 16:54:01.712 DEBUG 79836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ParameterizableViewController [view="forward:/index"]
2022-10-13 16:54:01.724 DEBUG 79836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
2022-10-13 16:54:01.724 DEBUG 79836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'forward:', model {}
2022-10-13 16:54:01.725 DEBUG 79836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [/index]
2022-10-13 16:54:01.728 DEBUG 79836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "FORWARD" dispatch for GET "/index", parameters={}
2022-10-13 16:54:01.734 DEBUG 79836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [static/], classpath [public/], classpath [], classpath [resources/], classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [META-INF/resources/webjars/]]
2022-10-13 16:54:01.736 DEBUG 79836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2022-10-13 16:54:01.736 DEBUG 79836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 404
2022-10-13 16:54:01.740 DEBUG 79836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
```

(Imports logs into snippet for viewing.)

If you check the log and approach "/", you are forwarding it to "/index".

So I changed the code to receive "/index" and process it.

---

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

---

It works for me.

Thank you.

Comment: I know /index is the default address when the url is only a domain name. I tried @RequestMapping("/") and localhost:8080 works but localhost:8080/index return 404, why my SpringBoot didn't forward "/"  to "/index"?

Comment: It can be delivered to the URL of "/" in the direction of "/index" upon request. 
However, it does not mean "/" == "/index".
Definition of access to "/index" is required.
If you want to have the same access to "/" and "/index".

@RequestMapping ("/index") is available.